# How to check ssh exit command executed?

Tags: shell, ssh

I want to check `exit` command is executed success in a ssh session.

My first attempt is using the command:

```
exit && echo $? || echo $?`.The `echo $? || echo $?
```

it should print `0` if exit successful.   The problem is `echo` never executes if `exit` execute success because connection is disconnected and the later command is lost.

My second attempt is splitting the command to two command, as this:

```
$ exit
$ echo $?
```

`echo $?` should be `0` if `exit` execute successful. But another problem is `echo $?` maybe be swallowed because it send so quickly that arrived to the remote ssh host before `exit` be executed.

So, how to ensure `exit` is executed at remote host before send next command?

### UPDATE #1

The using stage is I execute shell command at a program language and send message by a ssh pipe stream.So, I don't know the `exit` command executed time.If the `exit` command not completed, my follow commands will be swallowed because they send to the exiting host.
That is why I'm care about the `exit` command executed.

### UPDATE #2

#### 1. Which stage I am encountered the problem?

At beginning, I want to describe the problem as simply as possible but it seems more confusing. I am writing a SSH library with Scala language at [the git library](https://github.com/LoranceChen/scall).

It is not a interactive terminal. The response message from remote host is network IO stream, hold by the program, parse the result as String.That means, I must deal with every char codes and finally decide the command executed success or fail.

Some example code show as this:

```
//create a ssh by JSch library which is a SSH implement by Java Language.
val shell = Shell(Auth("host", "username", 22, "mypassword"))

//execute shell command as we do at terminal for example.
val rst1 = shell.exc("ls")

//create a new shell based on this shell.
val newShell = shell.newShell(Auth("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "username2", 22, "mypassword"))

//do something on the new shell
val rst2 = newShell.exc("touch somefile")

//exit from new shell
newShell.exit()
```

The `newShell` is created by `sshpass -p 'password' ssh -T username@hostname` as a normal command sent by `JSch`, so it is not any magic. It just like sending a normal command, such as `ls`.

The problem in the implement of the `exit()` method, if we ignore Scala code, it become those shell command:

```
$ echo '' && echo 'some-splitter-string' && exit
$ echo $? && echo 'some-splitter-string'
```

After sent that command to remote host what I expect response is this, but actually it not does, I'm explicitly append a `\n` character for read straightly:

```
\n
some-splitter-string\n
0\n
some-splitter-string\n
```

That means, I can split the IO stream by double `some-splitter-string` and get the inner `0`(maybe others) to decide the `exit` command execute completed, that is my protocol to decode a shell command result.

#### 2. What is the problem exactly?

Actually, the `exit()` command just response me:

```
\n  
some-splitter-string\n
```

The second command `echo $? && echo 'some-splitter-string'` is lost! That is because the command `$ echo $? && echo 'some-splitter-string'` also sent to the newShell host.

But after `exit` completed, this command is swallowed by the newShell host. Just consider this command simply `exit && touch somefile`. The later `touch somefile` never could be executed.

My current solution is sleep 1s after send `echo '' && echo 'some-splitter-string' && exit` command, it should be more elegance. So I want to find a way to ensure `exit` is executed and then I will send the second command to completed my protocol.

#### 3. Some question to clarify:

1. How could the "execution" of exit fail?
   Not exactly focus on fail or success at this point.That means, if `exit` can't be fail, just let me know it executed complete is ok.
2. Are we talking about a shell exit here?
   Yes, The aim of the question is find a way to decide the exit command executed complete in a ssh pipe environment.

Comment: "because connection is disconnected": is that not how you know it executed?

Comment: @MichaelHomer, after sleep 1s and send a `ls` command, it response my host files, so I think it exit success.Besides, the ssh is established from my host.

Comment: I think you need to [edit] to clarify what you mean and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Has updated.That is rarely encountered except at a ssh program in my sight.

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide some code that demonstrates what you are trying to do with your ssh session. I suspect this is an XY Problem and if you can show us why it's important to know that exit has worked we'll be able to suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: How could the "execution" of `exit` fail? Are we talking about a shell `exit` here? You may simply put `echo $exit_code` before the `exit $exit_code`. Or just `echo exiting` if you really call `exit` without a parameter.

Comment: more deeps explain about the question.